# I want to get user email and password from firebase but its give me an error . Validate email and password What should i do?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

This is the login activity of my application . Users registered successfully and all the details are stored in firebase but when i want to validate the user email and password it gives me error that "User not exist "
here is my code.
i want to validate the user email which is stored in realtime database if the email exist the user will login but if not it can give me error
same as for password

`package com.hamza.ebook;

```
    private boolean EmailValidate(){
        String value = email.getEditText().getText().toString();
        if (value.isEmpty()) {
            email.setError("Email error");
            return false;
        } else {
            email.setError(null);
            email.setErrorEnabled(false);
            return true;
        }

    }
    private boolean PasswordValidate(){
        String value = password.getEditText().getText().toString();
        if (value.isEmpty()) {
            password.setError("Password can not be empty ");
            return false;
        } else {
            password.setError(null);
            password.setErrorEnabled(false);
            return true;
        }

    }
    public void LoginUser(View view){
    if (!EmailValidate() | ! PasswordValidate()) {
        return;
    } else {
        isUser();
    }
    }


    private void isUser() {

        String userEnteredemail = email.getEditText().toString().trim();
        String userEnteredPassword = password.getEditText().toString().trim();

       reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");

        Query checkUser = reference.orderByChild("email").equalTo(userEnteredemail);
        checkUser.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                if (snapshot.exists()) {
                    email.setError(null);
                    email.setErrorEnabled(false);

                    String passwordFromDB = snapshot.child(userEnteredemail).child("password").getValue(String.class);

                    if (passwordFromDB.equals(userEnteredPassword)) {


                        String userNameDB = snapshot.child(userEnteredemail).getValue(String.class);
                        String emailNameDB = snapshot.child(userEnteredemail).getValue(String.class);
                        String PhoneNoDB = snapshot.child(userEnteredemail).getValue(String.class);

                        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, UserProfile.class);
                        intent.putExtra("name", userNameDB);
                        intent.putExtra("password", passwordFromDB);
                        intent.putExtra("email", emailNameDB);
                        intent.putExtra("Phone", PhoneNoDB);

                        startActivity(intent);


                    } else {
                        password.setError("Wrong Password");
                        password.requestFocus();
                    }
                } else {
                    email.setError("NO such User Exist");
                    email.requestFocus();
                }
            }


            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
    }
}
`
```

Comment: Have you tried to use hard-coded values? Please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/data).

Comment: @AlexMamo sir JSON file is added and i am new to android hard-coded values mean

Comment: I'm sorry but I cannot see the JSON file.

Answer (score 0):

I'll recommend you to try this method of authentication, it might help you.

**LoginActivity.java** (JavaFile)

```
package com.example.emailauthentication;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.ExtendedFloatingActionButton;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ExtendedFloatingActionButton signInBtn;
    private EditText emailEditText, passwordEditText;
    private FirebaseAuth auth;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        signInBtn=findViewById(R.id.signInButton);
        emailEditText =findViewById(R.id.editTextEmailS);
        passwordEditText =findViewById(R.id.editTextPasswordS);

        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        FirebaseUser user = auth.getCurrentUser();

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            String value = extras.getString("verification");
//            extras=null;
            if (value!=null && value.equals("pending")){
                new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                        .setTitle("Verification Pending")
                        .setMessage("We've sent you an verification email.\nPlease check your Given E-Mail ID inbox.")
                        .setNegativeButton(R.string.ok, null)
                        .setIcon(android.R.drawable.alert_dark_frame)
                        .show();
            }
        }

//      Redirect user to home page if already signed-in.
        if (user !=null){
            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,HomeActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }

//      SignIn OnClick
        signInBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                signInProfile();
            }
        });
    }

    private void updateUI(FirebaseUser getUser){

//      Checks if user is existing or not, on the basis of password and email.
        if (getUser==null){
            Toast.makeText(this, "E-mail ID / Password not Correct Or E-mail ID not registered yet.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Signing in...!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            if (!getUser.isEmailVerified()){
                Toast.makeText(this, "Verify your E-Mail ID", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

//          Transfer to Home Page after successful login.
            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    }

    private void signInProfile(){
        String email, password;
        email = emailEditText.getText().toString();
        password = passwordEditText.getText().toString();

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter email!!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter password!!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }

        auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            FirebaseUser user = auth.getCurrentUser();
                            updateUI(user);
                        } else {
                            updateUI(null);
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

**activity_login.xml** (layoutFile)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".LoginActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/sixteen"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/sixteen"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/thirtyFive"
            app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/sixteen"
            app:cardElevation="@dimen/twenty"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/color1">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/eight"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editTextEmailS"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/eight"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/eight"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:hint="@string/email"
                    android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editTextPasswordS"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/eight"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/eight"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/eight"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:hint="@string/password"
                    android:inputType="textPassword" />


            </LinearLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.ExtendedFloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/signInButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/fourty"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fourty"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/sign_in"
            app:icon="@drawable/signin"
            app:iconGravity="textStart" />

    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```